# Laravel : BadMethodCallException Method [show] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

> (1/1) BadMethodCallException
>
> Method [show] does not exist. in Controller.php (line 82)

I am new to Laravel and PHP and have been stuck on this error for a very long time with other questions not providing a solution. I was following an example (where the example worked) and made very little changes beside name changes.

Here is the code:

**web.php file**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('faq', 'PagesController@faq');
Route::resource('support', 'UserInfoController');
```

**UserInfoController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserInfo;

class UserInfoController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function create(){
        $userInfo = new UserInfo;
        return view('contact', ['userInfo' => $userInfo]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        UserInfo::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('contact')->with('success','Enquiry has been
         submitted successfully');
    }
}
```

**UserInfo.php**

```
namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class UserInfo extends Model {
        protected $fillable = [
          'name','email','subject','description',
        ];
    }
```

`The Route::resource` is the one giving me the problem as I am trying to access the page `support/contact`.  Would be very grateful if someone knew how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are doing resource routes in your routes.php file that generates all the routes for the CRUD functions when you have to generate a route for the show method you find that it does not exist. 
To solve it only creates the methods that you ask or, also you can define only the routes that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is trying to invoke the 'show' method - which you should have defined if you're going to load `/support/{id}` via `GET` in your browser. You can see the expected methods for a resource here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

You can also make your life somewhat easier by starting with a valid controller by using the built in generator:

```
php artisan make:controller UserInfoController --resource
```

If you don't want to supply ALL the methods, you have to specify, for example:

```
Route::resource('support', 'UserInfoController', ['only' => [
    'create', 'store'
]]);
```

Comment: When I change the route to that I get ' (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

in RouteCollection.php (line 179)'

Comment: Also the contact.blade.php page has a form that uses this line  {!! Form::model($userInfo, ['action' => 'UserInfoController@store']) !!}

Comment: @crazyPen I'm not sure what you're saying. You changed the route to what? You need to define all the methods that you put in the "only" parameter, or simply define all actions.

Comment: This is what I am having trouble understanding.  The example I am working off has the route like this: Route::resource('cars','CarController');  And it only defines the methods store and create in the CarController but it works.  So why does this example work without defining the other methods?

Comment: I discovered the issue.  The URL to access the page was support/create.   So why is the pretty URL support/create? Where exactly is the create extension defined?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added method `Show` to your `Controller` ? `Route::Resource` has 7 basic routes:

```
Verb    Path                        Action       Route Name
GET     /support                    index        support.index
GET     /support/create             create       support.create
POST    /support                    store        support.store
GET     /support/{support}          show         support.show
GET     /support/{support}/edit     edit         support.edit
PUT     /support/{support}          update       support.update
DELETE  /support/{support}          destroy      support.destroy
```

As you see there is a route called `show` which will be default when you route to `support` so you must connect this route to it's method in the controller which  is in `resource` case `CONTROLLER/show`, however in your case you're trying to get a static page from a prefix called `support` which is different from `resources` because `show` in resource handling `dynamic` results.
Use this syntax to get a page called `contact` from prefix called `support`

```
Route::prefix('support')->group(function () {
    Route::get('contact', function () {
    // Matches The "/UserInfoController/contact" URL
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem ended up being unrelated to this and the URL to access the page was support/create.  So where was the 'create' extension of the URL defined?